# Evaluate the combination of $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{{\lceil} \frac{k}{2} {\rceil}}\binom{N-k}{j}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can any one help me please to get the approximate result of this combination problem using asymptotic notation:

$$
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{{\lceil} \frac{k}{2} {\rceil}}\binom{N-k}{j}
$$

Thanks

Comment: Since $\lceil k/2 \rceil$ and $N - k$ are independent, you may as well phrase this as: find an asymptotic approximation to $\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{j}$, for integers $0 \leqslant m < n$.

Comment: By the way, if the signs were to alternate, a closed form would exist: $\sum_{j \leqslant m} \binom{r}{j}(-1)^j = (-1)^m \binom{r-1}{m}$ for all integer $m$ and real $r$. Also, if you take enough terms ($m \geqslant n$) then you would just have $\sum_j \binom{n}{j} = 2^n$.

Comment: Thanks Yakov Shklarov, Actually I solved it this way, since we know $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^k n^{i} 1^{k-i} = (1+n)^{k}$, using this we can solve the equation above as $O(1+(N-k))^{{\lceil} \frac{k}{2} {\rceil}}$. I am not sure yet, but that was my trial.

Comment: So it turns out that we can do better than an approximation! Although no hypergeometric closed form exists, [nczksv gives a closed form here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1254081/222048).