# Closed form for $ \sum_{l=0}^{2m} \binom{2m+n-1}{2m-l}x^l $

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to bound an operator and I arrived to a sum of the form
$$
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2m}\binom{2m + n - 1}{2m - \ell}x^{\ell},\qquad
\mbox{with}\quad0\le m\le n-1.
$$

Does this have a nice closed form ?

EDIT: This (quite obviously) transforms to
$$ x^{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{2m} \binom{2m+n-1}{k}x^{-k}. $$
So the question can be rephrased to ask about the closed form of the sum
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m+n}{k}x^{k}. $$

Comment: By "closed form" do you mean "in a fixed number of terms"?

Comment: No, I basically want to find a nice simple bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't have a closed-form for the following reason. It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180341/no-closed-form-for-the-partial-sum-of-n-choose-k-for-k-le-k) that even sum $\sum_{k = 0}^K \binom{N}{k}$ has no closed form. Without loss of generality we can assume that $K \le \frac{N}{2}$. Then

$$\sum_{k = 0}^K \binom{N}{k} = (K \bmod 2)\binom{N}{K} + \sum_{k = 0}^{2\left\lfloor\frac{K}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{N}{k} = (K \bmod 2)\binom{N}{K} + \sum_{k = 0}^{2m}\binom{2m + n - 1}{k}\\
= (K \bmod 2)\binom{N}{K} + \sum_{\ell = 0}^{2m}\binom{2m + n - 1}{2m - \ell}1^{\ell}$$

for $m = \left\lfloor\frac{K}{2}\right\rfloor$, $n = N - 2m + 1 > \frac{N}{2} \ge 2m \ge m$ and $\ell = 2m - k$. So if your sum had a closed form then $\sum_{k = 0}^K \binom{N}{k}$ would have too. This contradiction shows that your sum has no closed form.

Comment: In that case is there some kind of sharp bound for this sum?

Comment: @tst Perhaps you should create a separate question for that.

Comment: From what I understand from the linked question, the negative answer depends on the definition of closed form. But I cannot really follow the answers to this question. if we allow special functions? Does it then exist?

Answer (score 1):

You properly wrote that *it depends on the definition of closed form*.

If you accept hypergeometric functions to be a "closed" form, you will have
$$\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2m}\binom{2m + n - 1}{2m - \ell}x^{\ell}=\binom{2 m+n-1}{2 m} \, _2F_1(1,-2 m;n;-x)$$

Comment: Oh, that's great!

Comment: @tst. It is not so great ! It is still a summation. But again, as you said, *it depends on the definition of closed form.*. Cheers.

Comment: Well, hypergeometric functions have been studied a lot, so I hope I will be able to find a nice bound.