# How many distinct binary strings have Hamming distance at most $k$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Given a binary string of length $n$, how many distinct binary strings
>   have [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) at most $k$ from it?

There are ${n \choose k}$ sets of $k$ locations to flip a bit but many of those overlap. Is there a simple closed form for the value I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to count every bitstring that has edit distance $x$ from your original bitstring $b$ for all $x \leq k$. So the sum you're looking for is $$S = \sum_{x=0}^k {n \choose x}$$
which has [no closed-form expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180341/no-closed-form-for-the-partial-sum-of-n-choose-k-for-k-le-k) in general, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean edit distance or Hamming distance?

Comment: Yes - in this post I use Hamming distance and edit distance synonomously.