# Calculate how many 1-0 vectors satisfy a given eqation

Tags: combinatorics, vectors

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and consider $n$-dimensional 0-1 vectors $\bf{x} = [{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n}]$. That is, all $x_i \in \{ 0,1 \}$. For integer $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n$, calculate how many vectors $\bf{x}$ satisfy the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq k$$

I'm totally lost as to what to try here. I know there are $2^n$ possible vectors for any given $n$, and I want to choose some number $s$ of those vectors, so some form of $2^n\choose s$ seems to make sense, but I can't figure out if I'm on the right track.

EDIT: I'm realizing that order of the vectors matters, so something of the form $n\choose r$ will not make sense here.

Comment: You are not choosing vectors, you are choosing which components will be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RossMillikan is saying, this is a combinatorial problem. This problem is equivalent to the following standard problem:

Fix $n \ge 1$ and $n \ge k \ge 1$. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be $n$ many distinct objects. How many distinct ways are there to choose $k$ or more of the objects (so order doesn't matter, and without replacement)? For choosing precisely $k$ objects, see [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_3_unordered_without_replacement.php) (among many online resources) if you need further help.

Can you see why these problems are equivalent?

> the choice of objects $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ correspond to the which vector components $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are set equal to $1$ and which are set equal to $0$.

edit: clarified some language

Comment: But the order does matter. For instance the vectors [1 0 1] and [1 1 0] would be two distinct vectors that satisfy the equation if n=3,k=2. If n=4, k=3 for another example, you have to find all 5 vectors with at least 3 1's - you can't just call [1 0 1 1] and [1 1 1 0] the same vector. If order didn't matter, you'd say only 2 vectors satisfy the equation (4 with 3 1's and 1 with 4 1's). But that's incorrect.

Comment: Order matters in that sense but not that $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$ is different from $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 1)$.! Slowo is handling order in the first sense by requiring the objects $a_i$ to be distinct.

Comment: I understand how this works when I want to choose exactly k objects, but it's the "or more" aspect that is the entire crux of this problem.

Comment: It just seems like there should be something a little more elegant than {n choose k} + {n choose k+1} +...+{n choose n}

Comment: Yes, @badjohn is right. When choosing from the objects $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ the order in which you choose the objects does not matter. But since the objects are distinct, you can use them to identify which components of the vectors should be $1$ or $0$. This was the simplest way I could think to reformulate the problem into a standard combinatoric problem

Comment: And it seems as though you've figured out the solution :) I'm not sure how to address any qualms about elegance but at least it works, yeah? And using quite a standard combinatorics technique too, which I think is nice. Of course, others should feel free to present more elegant solutions if they have any

Comment: @J.O'connor There is no simpler formula for $\binom{n}k+\dots+\binom{n}n$. ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180341/no-closed-form-for-the-partial-sum-of-n-choose-k-for-k-le-k)). You should get accustomed to this in combinatorics; having a nice formula is the exception to the rule.