# Combinations from a set of disjoint sets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Forall $1 \le i \le n$, let $A_i$ be a set of $r_i > 0$ distinct elements (s.t. all $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint.). Also let $m := \sum_i r_i$.

I am interested in choosing $k$ elements from $\sqcup_i A_i$ - trivially you can see it would be $\binom{m}{k}$. But what if I started adding certain restrictions based on number of elements chosen from each set? For example:

(i) What is the number of ways (order not important) to choose $k$ elements from $\sqcup_i A_i$ s.t. I choose ATLEAST $t_1$ elements from $A_1$, $t_2$ elements from $A_2$ , ... $t_n$ elements from $A_n$?

(ii)  What is the number of ways (order not important) to choose $k$ elements from $\sqcup_i A_i$ s.t. I choose ATMOST $t_1$ elements from $A_1$, $t_2$ elements from $A_2$ , ... $t_n$ elements from $A_n$?

And then we can ask questions like choosing atleast $t_i$ from $A_i$ AND atmost $s_i$ from $A_i$ forall $i$ and so on? Is there a general method to solve such questions?

Note that the analog of this problem: If instead of choosing from $\sqcup A_i$, we are required to choose from a multiset, then the general method to solving such questions is to use generating functions. Is there any such general method here?

P.S: Throughout this question, I assume that you cannot repeat a choice of element (i.e. repition not allowed).

Comment: Have you worked out the answers for $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Comment: @aschepler I directly attempted it for general n. You can clearly write the number of ways to choose $k$ elements with exactly $k_i$ from $A_i$ forall $i$ s.t. $\sum_i k_i = k$. Then I was hoping to sum each $k_i$ with appropriate bounds. I got the summand as a product of two multinomial coefficients, but wasn't able to sum all of them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution using generating functions. For any integers $r,s,t$ with $s\le t\le r$, define the following generating function:
$$
f_{r,s,t}(x)=\sum_{i=s}^t \binom ri x^i
$$
This generating function represents choosing elements from a set of size $r$, such that at least $s$ and at most $t$ elements are chosen. There is no closed form for $f_{r,s,t}(x)$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180341/no-closed-form-for-the-partial-sum-of-n-choose-k-for-k-le-k) for the reason why).

This means that the generating function for choosing elements from disjoint sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ with cardinalities $r_1,\dots,r_n$, such that there are between $s_i$ and $t_i$ elements taken $A_i$ (inclusive) for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, is the product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f_{r_i,s_i,t_i}(x).
$$
In particular, the number of ways to choose exactly $k$ elements is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the above function.